# Working with series using Recursive function and Memoization in python

Tags: python, list, recursion, series, memoization

I am working with series like Fibonacci series... (In Fibonacci series the nth term is the sum of n-1 and n-2 only.)
But in my case I want to nth term is the sum of half of the previous terms..
for example:

```
n=5
Output should be: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]

n=12
Output should be: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 42, 84, 165, 330]
```

```
def my_function(n):
    
    list1=[0,1]
    for i in range(0,n-2):
        if(i>2):
            value=sum(list1[i//2+1:])
        else:
            value=list1[i]+list1[i+1]
        list1.append(value)
    return list1
    
print(my_function(5))
```

I have done this without recursive function but I am thinking how to do it using recursively and memoization. Can you help me to solve this..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write the Fibonacci Sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: I don't need a Fibonacci series I want nth term is the sum of half of the previous terms.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```py
# Python has a built-in decorator for memoizing any function automagically.

from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def my_func_rec(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [0]
    elif n == 2:
        return [0,1]
    else:
        prev = my_func_rec(n-1)
        prev.append(sum(prev[(n-1)//2:]))
        return prev

print(my_func_rec(12)) # [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 42, 84, 165, 330]
```